# How to install/update rvm on a remote EC2 machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

How to install/update rvm on a remote EC2 machine, since we would like to deploy our rails app and its dependencies on new EC2 instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use rvm-capistrano => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano#readme it has quite good description how to setup everything, I maintain example project to make sure it all works as expected: https://github.com/mpapis/ad - you can check it's [capistrano config](https://github.com/mpapis/ad/blob/master/config/deploy.rb) for details